# Does settler improvement cards affect settler wagon?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I play as Germans and in my deck, I want to add these two cards: `Textile Mill` and `Royal Mint`, both increases coin gather rate of villagers.

Will settler wagon gather rate also be improved if I add these cards ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they improve the French gatherer as well. This is because they're just a special version of a gatherer/villager but they're still a gather/villager at base.

[Here](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Settler_Wagon) is a list of improvement cards that affect them (towards the bottom it's a show/hide link)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **Yes, any of the improvement cards that affect settlers will also affect the german settler wagon.**

The AOE3 Wiki lists [each of the cards as improvements for the unit](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Settler_Wagon#Shipments), and the was a question exactly the same as yours on the [AOE forums](http://forum.agecommunity.com/forums/thread/834567.aspx#2)